# Build an array of returned JSON objects to iterate over a list of keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, foreach

Please take a look at this script first, it works fine on my site:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "text.json",
    success: function (data) {

        var keywords = ["Germany","England","Bayern","ManU"];  

        $(data).each(function (index, item) { 
            var nation = item.nation,
            club = item.club,
            title = item.title;

            $.each(keywords,function(i,keyword){ 
                if ($.inArray(keyword,nation)!=-1) {
                    $('.'+ title+'_'+keyword).html('Yes')
                }
                else {$('.'+ title+'_'+keyword).html('No')
                }
            });   
        },
        error: function () { }
  });
```

JSON:

```
[{"title":"A","club":"Bayern","nation":"Germany"},{"title":"B","club":"Verdy","nation":"Japan"},{"title":"C","club":"ManCity","nation":"England"}]
```

The script will loop over a list of `keywords` and check whether they exist in the returned object `item.nation`. 
I want to use the keyword list to check against other returned objects `item.title`,`item.club` as well. Can I build an array of the returned objects first to check against the keyword list? I have tried the following but it isn't working:

```
var keywords = ["Germany","England","Bayern","ManU"];  

$(data).each(function (index, item) {
    var objects = ['item.nation','item.club','item.title'];
    $.each(objects,function(i,object){ 
        $.each(keywords,function(i,keyword){ 
            if ($.inArray(keyword,object)!=-1) 
            {
                $('.'+ title+'_'+keyword).html('Yes')
            }
            else 
            {
                $('.'+ title+'_'+keyword).html('No')
            }
        });   
    });
});
```

Ideal Output should be like this:

```
<div class="AGermany>Yes</div>
<div class="BGermany>No</div>
<div class="CGermany>No</div>
<div class="AEngland>No</div>
<div class="BEngland>No</div>
<div class="CEngland>Yes</div>
<div class="ABayern>Yes</div>
<div class="BBayern>No</div>
<div class="CBayern>No</div>
<div class="AManU>No</div>
<div class="BManU>No</div>
<div class="CManU>Yes</div>
```

Comment: As you can see when I fixed your indentation, your braces aren't balanced properly.

Comment: You should also use `$.each(data, ...)`, not `$(data).each(...)`.

Comment: `keyword` and `nation` are both strings. What is `$.inArray(keyword, nation)` supposed to do? Maybe you meant `$.inArray(nation, keywords)`, and then you don't need the loop.

Comment: Are you talking about the first script? Isn't `$.inArray(keyword, nation)` suppose to check if a keyword in the array exists in item.nation?

Comment: `$.inArray(element, array)` tests whether `element` exists in `array`. But `item.nation` isn't an array.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. My focus is actually on the second example. I want to know how to build this array: `var objects = ['item.nation','item.club','item.title'];` in order to iterate over the keyword array. So the keyword list will be checked against these three objects. I'm using the first script and it has no problem at all.

Comment: Remove the quotes? `[item.nation, item.club, item.title]` will create an array of those three elements.

Comment: But you're still misusing `$.inArray()`, since `keyword` and `object` are both strings. The second argument has to be an array.